# Select Sqlite Query based condition

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a checkbox and recyclerview. I have to update list related to recyclerview on checkbox change

if checkbox ticked state Select Query like

```
     SELECT * 
     FROM tbl_code 
     WHERE isFavourite = 1
```

else unticked state Select Query like

```
     SELECT * 
     FROM tbl_code
```

how can I combine these two queries into one, so i can use a single query for two cases ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl_code where isFavourite = IFNULL(favourite,isFavourite)` should work ... i think it's `IFNULL` in sqlite

Comment: Why do you not want your code formatted?

Comment: it is not problem about query anymore.. But presentation layer!!

Comment: currently, I use 2 queries in checkbox change

Comment: if  join these 2 quries , it is easy for me

Comment: You first want to make this 2 select become one.. Now you change your requirement.. So what do you want?

Comment: Do something likle this: `String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_code";
if (checkbox.isChecked())
    sql += " WHERE isFavourite = 1";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);`

Comment: Post another question and ask it like that.. Because your first title and question `join two queries into a single one`

Answer (score 2):

From @Veljko89

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_code where isFavourite = IFNULL(favourite,isFavourite)
```

He answer your question in the comment..

Answer (score -1):

you could use below condition

```
select * from tbl_code  where 
Case when isFavourite 0 then 1
Else isFavourite end = 1
```

Comment: Union all.. union not replace the duplicate

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin he doesnt want data for both he wants one set or the other

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin do you understand what OP needs? He does not need the whole table my dear friend. This UNION returns the whole table always (no duplicates since there is no ALL)